# Two variables loop though a list in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a list `l = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]`

I want to loop through it using two variables:

```
   for x, y in ???:
      print x, y
```

I want to get the result like:

```
100, 200
200, 300
300, 400
400, 500
```

I know there are many ways to do it, but I am not sure which one is **elegant**. Please let me know if you know any **elegant** way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Answer (score 3):

Elegance is relative.  Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for x, y in zip(l, l[1:]):
    print x, y
```